# firemonkey android crc16 result mismatch with delphi for windows

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, crc16

in two different project i need to use crc16 checksum.one in windows and other in android.i used a code for windows and it worked prefect.

```
showmessage(  bin2crc16(HexToBin('1234'))    );   //---> 0EC9
```

here is used function for winsows

```
function Pow(i, k: Integer): Integer;
var
  j, Count: Integer;
begin
  if k>0 then j:=2
    else j:=1;
  for Count:=1 to k-1 do
    j:=j*2;
  Result:=j;
end;

function BinToDec(Str: string): Integer;
var
  Len, Res, i: Integer;
  Error: Boolean;
begin
  Error:=False;
  Len:=Length(Str);
  Res:=0;
  for i:=1 to Len do
    if (Str[i]='0')or(Str[i]='1') then
      Res:=Res+Pow(2, Len-i)*StrToInt(Str[i])
    else
    begin
      //MessageDlg('It is not a binary number', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
      Error:=True;
      Break;
    end;
  if Error=True then Result:=0
    else Result:=Res;
end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function CRC16CCITT(bytes: array of Byte): Word;
const
  polynomial = $1021;
var
  crc: Word;
  I, J: Integer;
  b: Byte;
  bit, c15: Boolean;
begin
  crc := $FFFF;
  for I := 0 to High(bytes) do
  begin
    b := bytes[I];
    for J := 0 to 7 do
    begin
      bit := (((b shr (7-J)) and 1) = 1);
      c15 := (((crc shr 15) and 1) = 1);
      crc := crc shl 1;
      if ((c15 xor bit) <> false) then crc := crc xor polynomial;
    end;
  end;
  Result := crc and $ffff;
end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function HexToDec(const Str: string): Integer;
begin
  if (Str <> '') and ((Str[1] = '-') or (Str[1] = '+')) then
    Result := StrToInt(Str[1] + '$' + Copy(Str, 2, MaxInt))
  else
    Result := StrToInt('$' + Str);
end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function bin2crc16(str: string): string;
var
I:integer;
lengthCount : integer;
crcByteArr : array of Byte;
crcOut : Word;
begin
  lengthCount := Trunc(length(str)/8);
  setlength(crcByteArr , lengthCount );
  for I := 0 to lengthCount-1 do
  begin
    crcByteArr[I] := BinToDec(copy(str, I*8+1, 8));
  end;
  crcOut := CRC16CCITT(crcByteArr);

  result := crcOut.ToHexString;

end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function HexToBin(Hexadecimal: string): string;
const
  BCD: array [0..15] of string =
    ('0000', '0001', '0010', '0011', '0100', '0101', '0110', '0111',
    '1000', '1001', '1010', '1011', '1100', '1101', '1110', '1111');
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  for i := Length(Hexadecimal) downto 1 do
    Result := BCD[StrToInt('$' + Hexadecimal[i])] + Result;
end;
```

but for android i changed the code to handle zero index string.
the result is different

```
memo2.Lines.Add( bin2crc16(HexToBin('1234')) ); //-----> 1AFa
```

here is used functions in android

```
function BinToDec(Str: string): Integer;
var
  Len, Res, i: Integer;
  Error: Boolean;
begin
  Error:=False;
  Len:=Length(Str);
  Res:=0;
  for i:=0 to Len-1 do
    if (Str[i]='0')or(Str[i]='1') then
      Res:=Res+Pow(2, Len-i)*StrToInt(Str[i])
    else
    begin
      Error:=True;
      Break;
    end;
  if Error=True then Result:=0
    else Result:=Res;
end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function CRC16CCITT(bytes: array of Byte): Word;
const
  polynomial = $1021;
var
  crc: Word;
  I, J: Integer;
  b: Byte;
  bit, c15: Boolean;
begin
  crc := $FFFF;
  for I := 0 to High(bytes) do
  begin
    b := bytes[I];
    for J := 0 to 7 do
    begin
      bit := (((b shr (7-J)) and 1) = 1);
      c15 := (((crc shr 15) and 1) = 1);
      crc := crc shl 1;
      if ((c15 xor bit) <> false) then crc := crc xor polynomial;
    end;
  end;
  Result := crc and $ffff;
end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function bin2crc16(str: string): string;
var
I:integer;
lengthCount : integer;
crcByteArr : array of Byte;
crcOut : Word;
begin
  lengthCount := Trunc(length(str)/8);
  setlength(crcByteArr , lengthCount );
  for I := 0 to lengthCount-1 do
  begin
    crcByteArr[I] := BinToDec(copy(str, I*8, 8));
  end;
  crcOut := CRC16CCITT(crcByteArr);

  result := crcOut.ToHexString;

end;
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function HexToBin(Hexadecimal: string): string;
const
  BCD: array [0..15] of string =
    ('0000', '0001', '0010', '0011', '0100', '0101', '0110', '0111',
    '1000', '1001', '1010', '1011', '1100', '1101', '1110', '1111');
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  for i := Length(Hexadecimal)-1 downto 0 do
    Result := BCD[StrToInt('$' + Hexadecimal[i])] + Result;
end;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function Pow(i, k: Integer): Integer;
var
  j, Count: Integer;
begin
  if k>0 then j:=2
    else j:=1;
  for Count:=1 to k-1 do
    j:=j*2;
  Result:=j;
end;
```

how can i fix my problem !?

Comment: Please don't include external links. Paste your code into the question.

Comment: @Dsm post updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not adjusted your HexToBin function for zero length strings.

There is also an issue in your BinToDec function. Your power calculation is wrong because the index into the string has changed. Possibly the simplest way to deal with it is as follows, although you could also adjust the index in the POW function

```
function BinToDec(Str: string): Integer;
var
  Len, Res, i: Integer;
  Error: Boolean;
begin
  Error:=False;
  Len:=Length(Str);
  Res:=0;
  for i:=1 to Len do
    if (Str[I - 1]='0')or(Str[I - 1]='1') then
      Res:=Res+Pow(2, Len-i)*StrToInt(Str[I - 1])
    else
    begin
      Error:=True;
      Break;
    end;
  if Error=True then Result:=0
    else Result:=Res;
end;
```

The last thing to note is that 'Copy' uses One based indexing even on zero based strings, but you have assumed that it is zero indexed. I agree it is confusing, but there it is.

Comment: i changed that line but not helped at all.

Comment: Did it give a different result?

Comment: yes, result changed but not match with windows yet!

Comment: value changed but not the same to windows yet! when i use `1234` as input windows show `0E39` but your code output is `CB65`..

Comment: Actually your Pow function is wrong, but wrong in both versions, so is not the issue here. Pow(2, 0) should be 1, not 2.

Comment: Are you sure you changed everything? Note that I now goes from 1 to Len and all the array elements are offet by 1 from what they were.

Comment: yes, i tested the function by this `BinToDec('1001000110100')` and it return `4660`

Comment: Please note my edit re Copy command. You will need to change all your start indexes wherever you used copy.

Comment: yes, the problem was in indexing of copy in `bin2crc16` function.its resolved now! Thank you